# Very slow download speeds with this code, any help improving it?

Tags: java, android, download

in my Android app I need to download a ~40 MB file, and I'm testing the code in my phone but the download speed is REALLY slow, I tried to download from different sources that are fast when using my PC.

Here is the code I use in the download service:

```
URLConnection conexion;
    URL url;
    int lenghtOfFile = 0;


    try {
        url = new URL("<URL>");
        conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();
        lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();


        try {

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testing");


            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, (int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile), false);
                notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, Long.toString(total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));

                notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getCause();
            e.getMessage();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


}
```

Is it possible that this code is the reason of the slow dl speeds? Any ideas on how to make the download speed faster?

Comment: Try to increase the buffer size, it will reduce the amount of I/O operations and can make your application work faster.

Comment: Updating the ui less often, for example only on every tenth iteration, might also improve performance.

Comment: You could also thread UI updates, with low priority.

Comment: Some good answers already listed, so I'll think a little bit laterally and ask is there any way you can reduce the size of the file? Can you compress it? Can you only send pieces of the file you need? etc, etc.

Comment: @PaulGrime     This is the minimum size I could get. they are already compressed. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
```

to

```
byte data[] = new byte[4096];
```

and as commonsware said,
update your download progress notification in less frequencies.

for eg:
use a simple counter variable in your loop, and update progress when it reaches 10, and then resetting it..!

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment?

Comment: sadly, i can't comment on questions..:(

Comment: This looks like a legitimate Answer to me.  (I don't think it will help though.)

Comment: Ah, yes. Silly SO rep rules :/

@StephenC Well, it's essentially what Egor was saying. What makes me hesitate is that it's not a definite "here's the answer" solution, but a "try and see" solution. Of course, Dipz can't comment, so this is what will work.

Comment: @RyanAmos - that doesn't make it not a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you would be better served using [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).
Android will download the file for you.
if DownloadProvider does not suit you, You could atleast benchmark your code.

Comment: DownloadManager is only for 2.3+ right? I'm interested in older devices too

Answer (score 2):

You are performing IPC every 1KB of download, as you update your `Notification`. For a 40MB file, this means you are performing approximately 40,000 IPC calls. Please update your `Notification` much less frequently.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didnt think of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the core problem is the network bandwidth / data rate that your (Android phone's) ISP is providing is much less than your PC gets via its LAN / broadband connection.  It could be that your phone is getting a weak signal from the local cell, or that the cell is overloaded, or the backbone is overloaded, or that your ISP has poor peering arrangements.

If that is the problem, there's not much you can do about it except (maybe) change phone carriers or reconfigure your (home?) networking so that your phone can use WiFi to talk to your local WiFi router.

Comment: All the testing I did was in WiFi so this wasnt the issue. Thanks for the answer anyway.